# Regex measurement like 100x100

Tags: regex

I have some text with different measures in that Im trying to exract with regex. 
a text can look something like this

```
Ipsum Lorem 3. 100x210 cm
Ipsum Lorem Lorem, 100x210 cm
```

I have got as far as I can extract the measurements, but when there is an int in the middle of the text ( like option 1) my regex fails.

```
([0-9x]+)(?:\^(-?\d+))?
```

Gets me

```
Match 1 : 100x210
Match 2  : 3
Match 3 : 100X210
```

Any suggestion on how I can skip match 2 and only regex INTxINT ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Use a character class to match x and X `\b\d+[xX]\d+\b` or use a capturing group `\b(\d+[xX]\d+) cm\b` https://regex101.com/r/06X6Jt/1

Comment: What may follow the substring of interest (to the end of the line)? It is `' cm'` in your examples. Must it be that? If not, could your string be `'Ipsum Lorem 3. 100x210 cm 7'` or `'Ipsum Lorem 3. 100x210 cm 80x90'`? If “yes” to the latter example, what is to be returned in that case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use a regex like

```
\d+x\d+
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/nl4VSk/1). It will match two substrings containing one or more digits separated with `x` character.

Comment: Such a nice regex! Thank you. this will help me in future ways

Answer (score 2):

Using a character class `[0-9x]+` could possibly also match only `xxx` or in this case, only `3`

The optional group in your pattern could possibly also match `100x210^-2`, not sure if that is intended as `\^` will match a caret.

To match both the lower and uppercase variant of x, you could use a character class `[xX]` or make the regex case insensitive.

Using word boundaries `\b` on the left and right:

```
\b\d+[xX]\d+\b
```

Or a more specific pattern using a capturing group, taking matching the `cm` part afterwards:

```
\b(\d+[xX]\d+) cm\b
```

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/06X6Jt/1)